# How would you address these nested Flexboxes with align-items: stretch?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is really difficult to express in words so I made this quick diagram:

[image]

The outer parent is flex with `align-items:stretch` so that col 1 and col 2 are both the same height. In my case it's because I have some border or background image that will just look better extending the same length. However... as you can see I want to apply the same rules to the columns inside those two columns. In my case I have an announcements widget in one and a news feed in the other. So I can't really combine the two to just make a single combined feed. They pull from different sources and operate independently with differing time stamps and rules SO... they really need to be separate components but because they are nested separately they do not both "fill" the outer columns equally. When the announcements in col 1 are too small, I get dead/neg space with no border or background texture or whatever extending all the way down.

The way I have resolved this in the past is to use JS to watch for which columns are longer and match height as needed. But this seems REALLY anti-flexbox. It feels like one major reason flexbox exists is to allow more layout functionality without needing JS and although it's a minor thing from a functionality standpoint where I could leave it and just say it is what it is... I am left wondering if there is some hidden magic in flexbox that would allow me to say if the parent>parent is stretching, than at least match that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

HTML:

```
<div class="outerContainer">

  <div class="innerContainer">

    <div class="col">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="innerContainer">

    <div class="col">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <h2>Column 4</h2>
      <p>some stuff</p>
      <p>some stuff</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outerContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.innerContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

https://codepen.io/McHat/pen/QzZExp

Comment: It is. I have to review my markup and such because I swear I did this same thing and it is not rendering as such which lead me to ask this question. Thanks for the assist.